# The local variable dMetres may not have been initialized

Tags: eclipse

```
        //create scanner class
        Scanner iKeyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        Scanner dKeyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        Scanner chKeyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        //assign variables
        int iInches;
        int iPounds;
        double dMetres;
        double dKilo;
        double dMetric;
        double dImp;
        char chChoice;
        char chI = 'I';
        char chM = 'M';

        //Ask the user to input M (metric) or I (imperial)
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter your details using the metric (M) or imperial system (I)");
        System.out.println("Please enter M or I: ");
        chChoice = chKeyboard.next().charAt(0);                             //Initialised variable

        //Ask the user to enter his weight and height but depending on it's choice of system
        if (chChoice == chM)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your weight in kilograms: ");
            dKilo = dKeyboard.nextDouble();                                 //Initialised variable
            System.out.println("Please enter your height in metres: ");
            dMetres = dKeyboard.nextDouble();                               //Initialised variable
        }
        else if (chChoice == chI)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
            iPounds = iKeyboard.nextInt();                                  //Initialised variable
            System.out.println("Please enter your height in inches: ");
            iInches = iKeyboard.nextInt();                                  //Initialised variable
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect value");
            System.out.println("Please enter M or I: ");
            chChoice = chKeyboard.next().charAt(0);
            if (chChoice == chM)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter your weight in kilograms: ");
                dKilo = dKeyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Please enter your height in metres: ");
                dMetres = dKeyboard.nextDouble();
            }
            else if (chChoice == chI)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
                iPounds = iKeyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Please enter your height in inches: ");
                iInches = iKeyboard.nextInt();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect value");
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                chChoice = chKeyboard.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }



        //Calculate the users BMI depending on users preferred system of measurement
        if (chChoice == chM)
        {
            dMetric = dKilo / (dMetres * dMetres);          //error on dKilo and dMetres
            System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + dMetric);
        }
        else
        {
            dImp = iPounds / (iInches * iInches) * 703;     //error on iPounds and iInches
            System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + dImp);
        }
```

It says that my variables have not been initialised but they have when I created the keyboards etc. chChoice has been initialised the same way and won't have any problems if i remove the chM, can someone fix this please?

If You are Curious Here is the functioning code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * 
 * @author 
 * @version 1 13/05/17
 * @aim to get the user to input their weight and height using their choice of measurement and then telling them their BMI and their category of weight for example obese
 */
public class L04BMICalculator 
{



    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        //create scanner classes
        Scanner dKeyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        Scanner chKeyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        //assign variables
        double dInches = 0;
        double dPounds = 0;
        double dMetres = 0;
        double dKilo = 0;
        double dMetric = 0;
        double dImp = 0;
        char chChoice;
        char chI = 'I';
        char chM = 'M';

        //Ask the user to input M (metric) or I (imperial)
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter your details using the metric (M) or imperial system (I)");
        System.out.println("Please enter M or I: ");
        chChoice = chKeyboard.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);                               

        //Ask the user to enter his weight and height but depending on it's choice of system
        if (chChoice == chM)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your weight in kilograms: ");
            dKilo = dKeyboard.nextDouble();                                 
            System.out.println("Please enter your height in metres: ");
            dMetres = dKeyboard.nextDouble();                               
        }
        else if (chChoice == chI)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
            dPounds = dKeyboard.nextDouble();                                   
            System.out.println("Please enter your height in inches: ");
            dInches = dKeyboard.nextDouble();                                   
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect value");      //If user entered something else this would come up
            System.out.println("Please enter M or I: ");                    //Asks the user to try again
            chChoice = chKeyboard.next().charAt(0);
            if (chChoice == chM)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter your weight in kilograms: "); 
                dKilo = dKeyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Please enter your height in metres: ");
                dMetres = dKeyboard.nextDouble();
            }
            else if (chChoice == chI)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
                dPounds = dKeyboard.nextDouble();   
                System.out.println("Please enter your height in inches: ");
                dInches = dKeyboard.nextDouble();   
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect value");  //Says the same thing as before if they ignore previous instruction but....
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");                             //Failure to oblige leads to termination 
                chChoice = chKeyboard.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }//end if

        //Calculate the users BMI depending on users preferred system of measurement
        if (chChoice == chM)
        {
            dMetric = dKilo / (dMetres * dMetres);          
            System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + dMetric);
        }
        else
        {
            dImp = dPounds / (dInches * dInches) * 703;     
            System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + dImp);
        }

        //Using the knowledge gained assign the user's BMI to a specific set for example, under weight 
        if (dMetric <= 18.5)
        {
            System.out.println("If ones BMI is 18.5 or less they are usually cosidered to be underweight");
        }
        else if (dMetric > 18.5 && dMetric <= 24.99)
        {
            System.out.println("If ones BMI is between 18.6 and 24.99 they are usually cosidered to be of average weight (normal)");
        }
        else if (dMetric > 24.99 && dMetric <= 29.99)
        {
            System.out.println("If ones BMI is between 25 and 29.99 they are usually cosidered to be overweight");
        }
        else if (dMetric > 29.99 && dMetric <= 34.99)
        {
            System.out.println("If ones BMI is between 30 and 34.99 they are usually cosidered to be in obese class 1");
        }
        else if (dMetric > 34.99 && dMetric <= 39.99)
        {
            System.out.println("If ones BMI is between 30 and 34.99 they are usually cosidered to be in obese class 2");
        }
        else if (dMetric > 39.99)
        {
            System.out.println("If ones BMI is greater than 40 they are usually cosidered to be morbidly obese ");
        }//end if

        if (dImp <= 18.5)
        {
            System.out.println("If ones BMI is 18.5 or less they are usually cosidered to be underweight");
        }
        else if (dImp > 18.5 && dImp <= 24.99)
        {
            System.out.println("If ones BMI is between 18.6 and 24.99 they are usually cosidered to be of average weight (normal)");
        }
        else if (dImp > 24.99 && dImp <= 29.99)
        {
            System.out.println("If ones BMI is between 25 and 29.99 they are usually cosidered to be overweight");
        }
        else if (dImp > 29.99 && dImp <= 34.99)
        {
            System.out.println("If ones BMI is between 30 and 34.99 they are usually cosidered to be in obese class 1");
        }
        else if (dImp > 34.99 && dImp <= 39.99)
        {
            System.out.println("If ones BMI is between 30 and 34.99 they are usually cosidered to be in obese class 2");
        }
        else if (dImp > 39.99)
        {
            System.out.println("If ones BMI is greater than 40 they are usually cosidered to be morbidly obese ");
        }//end if

        //Close keyboard
        dKeyboard.close();
        chKeyboard.close();

    }//end main

}//end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second condition check block, there is no dMetres intialized. If it is false, at the end of the code when u calculate BMI, there is no variable initialized. Hence eclipse suggests you to initialize so that in every condition block, the variable has atleast a default value.

Intialize your variable to null or default value like 0;

Here is the whole program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMICalc {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //create scanner class
        Scanner iKeyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        Scanner dKeyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        Scanner chKeyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        //assign variables
        int iInches = 0;
        int iPounds = 0;
        double dMetres = 0;
        double dKilo = 0;
        double dMetric;
        double dImp;
        char chChoice;
        char chI = 'I';
        char chM = 'M';

        //Ask the user to input M (metric) or I (imperial)
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter your details using the metric (M) or imperial system (I)");
        System.out.println("Please enter M or I: ");
        chChoice = chKeyboard.next().charAt(0);                             //Initialised variable

        //Ask the user to enter his weight and height but depending on it's choice of system
        if (chChoice == chM)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your weight in kilograms: ");
            dKilo = dKeyboard.nextDouble();                                 //Initialised variable
            System.out.println("Please enter your height in metres: ");
            dMetres = dKeyboard.nextDouble();                               //Initialised variable
        }
        else if (chChoice == chI)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
            iPounds = iKeyboard.nextInt();                                  //Initialised variable
            System.out.println("Please enter your height in inches: ");
            iInches = iKeyboard.nextInt();                                  //Initialised variable
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect value");
            System.out.println("Please enter M or I: ");
            chChoice = chKeyboard.next().charAt(0);
            if (chChoice == chM)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter your weight in kilograms: ");
                dKilo = dKeyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Please enter your height in metres: ");
                dMetres = dKeyboard.nextDouble();
            }
            else if (chChoice == chI)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
                iPounds = iKeyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Please enter your height in inches: ");
                iInches = iKeyboard.nextInt();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect value");
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                chChoice = chKeyboard.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }



        //Calculate the users BMI depending on users preferred system of measurement
        if (chChoice == chM)
        {
            dMetric = dKilo / (dMetres * dMetres);          //error on dKilo and dMetres
            System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + dMetric);
        }
        else
        {
            dImp = iPounds / (iInches * iInches) * 703;     //error on iPounds and iInches
            System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + dImp);
        }



    }





}
```

Comment: What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Updated my answer. Full program.

Comment: Hello again, the code works but only for Metric. The output of I is just 0.0

Comment: Would you like to enter your details using the metric (M) or imperial system (I)
Please enter M or I: 
I
Please enter your weight in pounds: 
13
Please enter your height in inches: 
5
Your BMI is: 0.0
If ones BMI is 18.5 or less they are usually cosidered to be underweight
If ones BMI is 18.5 or less they are usually cosidered to be underweight

Comment: Do you think you can fix this for me please?

Comment: I have found the cause of these errors and have corrected them, Sorry for wasting your time.